# how to hide blank property field from orders in shopify

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, shopify, liquid

I have created a gift note functionality which store notes but the problem is it is showing title on orders even though textarea is blank could you please help to get rid of this problem
if textarea is blank still order page is showing "cart note:"

```js
{% if line_item.properties != empty %}
        <ul class="CartItem__PropertyList">
          {% for property in line_item.properties %}
          {% assign first_character_in_key = property.first | truncate: 1, '' %}

          {% if property.last == blank or first_character_in_key == '_' %}
          {% continue %}
          {% endif %}

          <li class="CartItem__Property">{{ property.first }}: <p class="cart_note_txt">{{ property.last }}</p></li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
```

```html
  <textarea class="gift_note_pro" maxlength="300" name="properties[Cart Note]" style="display:none;" placeholder="Add a note">                    
                  </textarea>
```

Can someone help me to get rid of this problem ?